# Select date returning incorrect values? MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

Very very simple query as follows:

```
select distinct start_date from calls_list where start_date >=  '06/06/2012 00:00:00';
```

Returns

```
06/06/2012 09:27:40
06/06/2012 09:28:08
06/06/2012 09:28:18
06/06/2012 09:29:18
31/05/2012 07:02:46
31/05/2012 07:04:22
31/05/2012 07:04:35
31/05/2012 07:08:16
```

And I'm scratching my head... Any ideas?  I'm from a MSSQL background, so it may be that MySQL handles dates and times differently?

Comment: what is the datatype of `start_date`? I hope it is `DATETIME`, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I'm trying to troubleshoot something that someone handed over to me, so I'll have to check. It's a ridiculously complicated way of doing what is happening is a report is being exported as a CSV and then imported into MySQL using a PHP script.  The date format in the report is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss so having to emulate that (or maybe that's where the issue is)

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? You can check this by running `DESCRIBE calls_list` query. BTW, regardless of database background, dates should be stored as dates and transformed upon insert/select.

Comment: Looks as thought that's what's happened. Seems that the CSV importer is rather a pain to get working with things other than text, so I'll try using the str_to_date function and see if I have any luck with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `start_date` is `DATETIME` field. Every row is different - same date, but different time. I suggest:

`select distinct DATE(start_date) from calls_list where start_date >=  '06/06/2012 00:00:00';`